# Custom Number Pad UIKeyboard

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uikeyboard

**How would I go about creating a custom number pad like what is used in 'Tipulator' and other apps.**

I know how you can customize UIKeyboard, but their number pad doesn't look at all like the default number pad. Is it even a UIKeyboard or a separate UIView?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been working with keyboards for quite a time. I would say that the easiness of this depends on what your target text input view is. If is a UITextView then we are fine, if is UITextField you might have some problems because you don't have access to current cursor text position like un UITextView.
(You might check UITextView and UITextViewDelegate methods)

If you just want to set a string and don't mind current cursor text position, then you don't need a keyboard. (I think this is the case of Tipulator)

BTW: I just saw Tipulator in youtube and there is no necessity of a keyboard for doing that.

Comment: That's what I suspected. But how would the delete button work and how would the number be added on to the end?

Comment: I don't see any way to know about current position of cursor within a UITextView, even not with the help of UITextFieldDelegate. This answer is flawed. I mean - without inserting something. With the custom keybard I'm supposed to insert the text in a particular position - and that's what I need to know before the insertion - so before firing the delegate method. Delegate method is called only when changing the text, not when just moving around textView with arrow keys.

Comment: UITextViewDelegate will tell you the WHEN (textViewDid...), and -(NSRange)[UITextView selectedRange] will tell you the WHERE. UITextField does not have selectedRange method and this is why I said that with UITextView is easy.

Answer (score 0):

Judging by the looks: It's a custom UIView subclass. Basically, it's just a panel with 11 buttons on it, so it should be rather easy to do.